# How do I install Ubuntu Server on a local machine without a monitor?

Tags: server, system-installation, display

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a old server of mine but it has a VGA slot and my monitor has only HDMI and mDP.

Is there a way to put a Ubuntu Server installation stick into it and connect via ssh? Or maybe to do an unattended install?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Depends upon your skill level. If you already know how to do an [unattended server install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs), then it's likely to work. If you have never done one before, then it's possible...but it's not a beginner-level task. You might want to practice a few times on a Virtual machine before trying on bare metal. it might be faster and easier to borrow a friend's VGA monitor for the afternoon.

Comment: Did you have a chance with what is explained in https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general ?

Comment: You could also get a $10 adapter.